# jquery table header clone issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix a table header using jquery clone function. Clone function works properly but before scroll my header is not visible. After scroll the cloned table works properly. Need to show table header before scroll and cloned table header after scroll

```
var tableOffset = $("#myTable").offset().top;
var $header = $("#myTable > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);
$(".table-container").bind("scroll", function () {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.fadeIn(2000);
    } else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedHeader.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle for this

Comment: And/or show your CSS related to `#myTable`, `thead`, `#header-fixed` and anything else relevant.

Comment: It would seem odd that you'd compare your $(".table-container").scrollTop() with your $("#myTable").offset().top.. what is the relation of these two values? one is the offset of the table from the top of the viewport.. the other I'm assuming is the <tbody> scrollTop.. right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="new_btn" value="NEW" onclick="add()">

<table>
    <tr id="col_tr" style="display: none">
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="inc_btn" id="inc_" value="+">
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty_" value="0">
            <input type="button" name="dec_btn" id="dec_" value="-">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
    var i = 0;

    function add() {
        if (i < 3) {
            var template = $("#col_tr").clone();
            template.css('display', '');
            template.prop('class','main');
            template.find("#inc_").replaceWith('<input type="button" name="inc_btn" onclick="increment(' + i + ')" id="inc_' + i + '" value="+">')
            template.find("#qty_").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty_' + i + '" value="0">')
            template.find("#dec_").replaceWith('<input type="button" name="dec_" id="dec_' + i + '" onclick="decrement(' + i + ')" value="-">')
            $("#col_tr").after(template);
            i++;
        }else{
            $(".main").remove();
            i=0;
        }
    }

    function increment(j) {
        var val = $("#qty_" + j).val();
        var total = ++val;
        $("#qty_" + j).val(total);
    }

    function decrement(j) {
        var val = $("#qty_" + j).val();
        var total = --val;
        $("#qty_" + j).val(total);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your answer is code only, and so it is unnecessarily hard hard to figure out how it solves OP's problem. I would suggest to add some explanation.